# Checkboxes render differently in light and dark mode

Tags: android

I have a row of checkboxes which seems to get extra spacing in dark mode. This is the XML for one of the checkboxes:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true" />
```

This is how the checkboxes look in light mode:

[image]

And in dark mode:

[image]

The issue exists both in the Android Studio design view and in the physical device: there is extra space around the boxes in dark mode. How do  remove this extra space?

Answer (score 0):

by the looks of your code , you didn't use any kind of styling , so i'm amusing you styled all of your CheckBoxs on your app's theme style.

if so :

1. on your [normal] and [-night] style.xml , maybe you used different options for styling CheckBoxs
2. on same styling values , maybe you used different parents

Comment: I am using the Material theme, and I didn't style my checkboxes in either of the two modes. Also, in both cases the parent is a ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try the classic invalidate caches and restart and if the issue still pertains then the problem must be with your grid adding extra padding in dark mode.